# How to query dataset table on primary key of smallInt using linq C#

Tags: linq, dataset

Let say I have the following sql table. Customer_id column is a primary key with smallint.

[image]

And I am trying to create a linq query, where I want to get all data for customer with id, let say 1.

How to do this.

[image]

Already done and not working:

1.

> ```
>         var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
>             where row.Field<Int32>("customer_id") == Convert.ToInt32(2)
>             select row;
> ```

2.

> ```
>         var query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
>             where row.Field<Int16>("customer_id") == Convert.ToInt16(2)
>             select row
> ```

3. debug for example 1,2

[image]

3. Syntax error

[image]

4. Exceptions

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. Since `customer_id` is the primary key, the row must be unique, why do you want to return a collection? Why use LINQ, if you could just use the Find() Method of the DataRowCollection-object?

Comment: Yes, you are right, collection does not make sense, I am new into datasets...how to use Find() ...can you give me pls some hint..

Comment: Have you created a .dbml file for your data tables?

Comment: yes I am using this sample database http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx

Comment: The link to the sample database you have given does not match the table described in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use this:

```
DataRow needle = hayStack.Tables["Customer"].Rows.Find(2);
```

Your method should be rewritten as something like this:

```
private DataRow GetCustomerDetails(Int16 customer_id)
{
     return _dt.Tables["Customer"].Rows.Find(customer_id);
}
```

The calling method would have to check for `null` beeing returned from the method, since an invalid customer_id would cause `Find()` tu return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `short` type instead of `Int32`.